# A typescript type implemented in typescript 4.4 can work in a proper way , but not in typescript 4.5+

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, typescript-typings

I am working on a [question](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00008-medium-readonly-2/README.md) from [type-challenges](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges).

This is the requirements: Implement a generic MyReadonly2<T, K> which takes two type argument T and K.

**K specify the set of properties of T that should set to Readonly. When K is not provided, it should make all properties readonly just like the normal Readonly.
The solution works fine in v4.4+, not in v4.5+.**

```
//solution 1
type MyReadonly2<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = T & {
  readonly [P in K]: T[P]
}
```

Reproduce the problem:

The solution in v4.7.2 :  [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/PQKgUABBAcELQQEoFMCGATA9gOwDYE8IAmSeOci0gI0IEFsAXACx0IDEBXCACgAFVGAMw4BKCAGIAtsnQBLDpIkAnNFjyFxmKgCtkAYwZwA1snwBnUqXHWIARQ7IzDWTktQAkpIAOuZNMYQqBAA5sjYyEqyehAABgCy%20CgYOAREADwAKgA0EADSAHwxEADuTFFMEAyoJmaVxZiV%20F7IgUrBCmEMsRlFAuixuTEAdG4DRWbNerKChMwtZshdmIIQXkqYzUrOjhDL3UXMqF1mLBy4-QtdDA1JagRDEADqTGFjELK12Jhda5gAbrJ0DIcrJjqdzhBJNUWqhcLhVutNttaipkuoINoOE4ILhZCZKi8IF8lFD4TFbil8JlCiMoKQ2JglBBkAAPVDeXyjGLchgWKCyRgRQSoPQtDKYLAQADepCgzgYvgAXBAnJFsMFZRAgWY9JEvM4cMrVQKNVAoHpMBzFjJlVRMJhfAJSABfUYW7DY65YZUJCnqdLirA5ADk8t8wYgAB8IMHtbrZPqXNhg-kIABeaWasPIZUAIgAEqZc1lNXG9QbsHnBPaqKglMXNRarQwbRBhbgFiWoK66XKJZghtn0xAC8g4ZhcxBgMAIABRJTrJTKvQCL5dVFmMyyYLYQIQVF3Qi-JH4UhegdlhMV4e52tKBkTqcz%20eL5er777tCb7e7oIHykIhsEQMKefZYEMTY%20Na-QZgwSgOE%20EAAPK5KQ3IxKMqYAGqyMgxS7LuADioL5hwVDKkwDAMF4ZiKtOvJ6EwQzaGYQyMsEwDQGAIDAGAfGgBAAD6wkiaJIkQAAmpgHBMgAwhKLSFioQliapgkQDxfEgc0EC%20qolIBjkuTMiyLbYOgtQmPgewZMOVk2amGa2QAZJmUD-uiADaAAK7y7rkAC6yoZD5AVgK6-EgCpamiRAGSOF0smoAstQxWJGm8bI3iMlcTQtFKEC0LiJg5LOLKTF0zptusijBrw2nIHAjGwr46qOMAHDOB2wZaXlEArilw6eaQZUVWkRV4sgaR6WiqSZP2ACM%20Q5H6BDzVgS35MtI3lfoDDjcVU0zYeAaLSG2YRtGsaOPGiY4CmpW7QYMhbV2c5PftE0mNNiT6f662YEQ52guGUYxped3Jst70VS921hWAAotkowqinFi1uZUIM5iqcEmqQEMVgA-EaePqqQkG%20C26C2vajrYOFfFI0KIpiv2RCYx5BBYwqOPGuTUCE0mJO42qpr9ZaUHU7TDpoAzEXMyjrMw3tMic393PZqTYukFzhBCzgIv8%20LlPQTL9OM3xYACWlsWcFsLxMgAyi2NHRbbGXW%20AUCpk7TB1i01kySqDqdUmtEQJR1G0fROpMSxbFtJxwACGYxQRKQ2G4fhZihxWEdRzRdHAAx8esexye57gYc4HyECpnEjItLJ-twmEoQF1RRex4xzHl203G8WAQA)

To fix this problem:

```
// solution 2
type MyReadonly2<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & {
  readonly [P in K]: T[P]
}
```

It works fine in V4.7.2. [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/PQKgUABBAcELQQEoFMCGATA9gOwDYE8IAmSeOci0gI0IEFsAXACx0IDEBXCACgAFVGAMw4BKCAGIAtsnQBLDpIkAnNFjyFxmKgCtkAYwZwA1snwBnUqXHWIARQ7IzDWTktQAkpIAOuZNMYQqBAA5sjYyEqyehAABgCy%20CgYOAREADwAKgA0EADSAHwxEADuTFFMEAyoJmaVxZiV%20F7IgUrBCmEMsRlFAuixuTEAdG4DRWbNerKChMwtZshdmIIQXkqYzUrOjhDL3UXMqF1mLBy4-QtdDA1JagRDEADqTGFjELK12Jhda5gAbrJ0DIcrJjqdzhBJNUWqhcLhVutNttaipkuoINoOE4ILhZCZKi8IF8lFD4TFbil8JlCiMoKQ2JglBBkAAPVDeXyjGLchgWKCyRgRQSoPQtDKYLAQADepCgzgYvgAXBAnJFsMFZRAgWY9JEvM4cMrVQKNVAoHpMBzFjJlVRMJhfAJSABfUYW7DY65YZUJCnqdLirA5ADk8t8wYgAB8IMHtbrZPqXNhg-kIABeaWasPIZUAIgAEqZc1lNXG9QbsHnBPaqKglMXNRarQwbRBhbgFiWoK66XKJZghtn0xAC8g4ZhcxBgMAIABRJTrJTKvQCL5dVFmMyyYLYQIQVF3Qi-JH4UhegdlhMV4e52tKBkTqcz%20eL5er777tCb7e7oIHykIhsEQMKefZYEMTY%20Na-QZgwSgOE%20EAAPK5KQ3IxKMqYAGqyMgxS7LuADioL5hwVDKkwDAMF4ZiKtOvJ6EwQzaGYQyMsEwDQGAIDAGAfGgBAAD6wkiaJIkQAAmpgHBMgAwhKLSFioQliapgkQDxfEgc0EC%20qolIBjkuTMiyLbYOgtQmPgewZMOVk2amGa2QAZJmUD-uiADaAAK7y7rkAC6yoZD5AVgK6-EgCpamiRAGSOF0smoAstQxWJGm8bI3iMlcTQtFKEC0LiJg5LOLKTF0zptusijBrw2nIHAjGwr46qOMAHDOB2wZaXlEArilw6eaQZUVWkRV4sgaR6WiqSZP2ACM%20Q5H6BDzVgS35MtI3lfoDDjcVU0zYeAaLSG2YRtGsaOPGiY4CmpW7QYMhbV2c5PftE0mNNiT6f662YEQ52guGUYxped3Jst70VS921hWAAotkowqinFi1uZUIM5iqcEmqQEMVgA-EaePqqQkG%20C26C2vajrYOFfFI0KIpiv2RCYx5BBYwqOPGuTUCE0mJO42qpr9ZaUHU7TDpoAzEXMyjrMw3tMic393PZqTYukFzhBCzgIv8%20LlPQTL9OM3xYACWlsWcFsLxMgAyi2NHRbbGXW%20AUCpk7TB1i01kySqDqdUmtEQJR1G0fROpMSxbFtJxwACGYxQRKQ2G4fhZihxWEdRzRdHAAx8esexye57gYc4HyECpnEjItLJ-twmEoQF1RRex4xzHl203G8WAQA)

---

I just can't figure out the reason why the solution 1 doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original behavior was considered a bug in TypeScript, filed at [microsoft/TypeScript#45122](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45122), fixed in [microsoft/TypeScript#45263](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45263), which was released in TypeScript 4.5.

How should TypeScript represent the [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of object types with a property of the same key where some, but not all of these are [`readonly` properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties)?  Should the resulting property be `readonly` or not?  For example, should `{readonly a: string} & {a: string}` be equivalent to `{readonly a: string}` or `{a: string}`?

Conceptually, and despite the name, `readonly` means "this is readable" while non-`readonly` means "this is readable *and* writable".  That is why you can treat an `Array<string>` as a `ReadonlyArray<string>`, but not vice versa.  Intersections conceptually mean "and", so `{readonly a: string} & {a: string}` should be an object with a readable `a` property, and an object with a readable and writable `a` property.  That implies the final `a` property is readable and writable, and so the final object type should be equivalent to `{a: string}`, without the `readonly` modifier.  By that logic, a final object property should only be `readonly` if it is `readonly` in *every* intersection member in which it appears.  Intersections cannot be used to *add* a `readonly` modifier to a property that is not `readonly`.

Before TypeScript 4.5, TypeScript had the opposite and incorrect behavior, where a final object property was `readonly` if it was `readonly` in *some* intersection member.  This was wrong, and it was fixed.

---

And that's why your code changed in TypeScript 4.5.  Something like `T & Readonly<Pick<T, K>>` shouldn't be able to *add* a `readonly` modifier to any of the keys in `K`, because those keys are also present in `keyof T`.  But `Omit<T, K> & Readonly<Pick<T, K>>` can add `readonly` modifiers because none of the keys in `K` are present in `keyof Omit<T, K>`.  You should get the same effect with `Omit<T, K> & Readonly<T>`, since you don't need to exclude the other keys.